# Azure Region Specific Data

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, multi-tenant

We have SAAS (Multi Tenant) based Application developed and deployed on Azure.

We are using Cloud Service, File Service, Blob Storage, Queue Storage, Elastic DB.

now our requirement is US Users only have data for US in their storage and Europe user have only data for Europe.  So, Region wise Datastorage.

We will have two different instance running for US and Europe.

for US Tenant all data should resides on US. UK based Tenant data should only in UK.

What is BEST Practices to do achieve this?

Comment: Is there even another option besides spinning up an Azure Storage account in a US data center, and a second one in a Europe data center, then factoring out the Storage account connection strings into your configuration file?

Comment: If you have these `DataConnectionString` configured in AppSettings or in ConnectionStrings, you can move them to portal.azure.com for easy maintenance and deployment.

Comment: You can configure a Network Security Group and create the applications / services within that group so that they are geographically confined to that group.